# what is the best way to call jsp page?

Tags: jsp, servlets, web-applications

I am building a web app project. 
And I have a Navigation bar on the top of the main jsp page. What I want is to use that nav bar to call another jsp page.
There are options availiable that I could handle:
1. using anchor with href;
2. using form with buttons that changes the destination value at action attribute.

But if I use anchor I cannot call servlet classes that are in WEB-INF folder.
And if I use form for submitting its not practical for me.

Are there any other options available?

Comment: you can use anchor tag for calling servletse. It should only map to the url.

Comment: You should study some tutorial, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html

Comment: Mr. Prasad Kharkar, do you mean servlet-mapping in web.xml file or something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the entry like this in web.xml

```
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>packagename.Servlet_filename</servlet-class>
 </servlet>  
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/ServletNamePath</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Now use

```
<a href="ServletNamePath">Redirect to Servlet</a>
```